# How do i get my loading.svg to be smaller on website

Tags: svg

i have a loading animation on my productfilter (shown on [THIS](http://www.zilvertron.com/motoren/) page). If you make a choice in the filter to the left you see the animation. Now i would like to make this a bit smaller but i do not know how to manage this. If i change the width & height ect. it changes the size of the svg but on the website it will still remain the same size (not a cache problem because colors do change). Any help would be really apreciated.

Thanks for your time,

Sjoerd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your page, the code that opens the loader animation is setting the width and height of the `<img>` tag, that loads the SVG, to `"100%"`.

```
<img style="height: 100%;width: 100%" src=".../loading-spin.svg">
```

This tells the browser that you want the image to be scaled to 100% of the size of its parent container.  That will happen whatever image format you are using. It has nothing to do with the image being an SVG. The same would be true if it was a GIF or a PNG.

The animation is the size it is because the parent container (a `<div>`) is styled to be 600px x 600px.

```
#woof_svg_load_container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    ...
}
```

If you want it to be smaller, modify the CSS for that container. For example:

```
#woof_svg_load_container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    ...
}
```